# wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0) custom redirect on devise login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Im building out a Ruby 2.4.0 / Rails 5.1 app.

Im having a problem on user login. Each user is assigned a role when created by an admin (this is an enum found in the user model).

When I try to login under any assigned role the user will be redirected to their roles corresponding dashboard. ie dashboard/admin or dashboard/dispatch

When I try to login in right now I get the following error that originates in the `DashboardController`

```
ArgumentError at /dashboard/dispatch
wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0)
```

screenshot:

[image: Better errors screenshot]

my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if current_user.role == "dispatch"
    dashboard_dispatch_path
  else
    root_path
  end
end

end
```

my dashboard controller:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def admin
  end

  def dispatch
  end

  def owner
  end

  def driver
  end

  def client
  end

  def guest
  end

end
```

rails server stack trace:

```
Started POST "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-01 12:57:29 -0600
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EeqNi1e+o5XDCaf9mci+Ce6keoU0DHiVRWwJiqtJA8JQ8rXa8KdnqZG39wTz+PTu52GoY/As8GwoUdKBLOX3vA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = $1, "last_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = $5  [["current_sign_in_at", "2018-04-01 18:57:29.348053"], ["last_sign_in_at", "2018-04-01 18:56:44.743086"], ["sign_in_count", 10], ["updated_at", "2018-04-01 18:57:29.348921"], ["id", 2]]
   (1.0ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/dashboard/dispatch
Completed 302 Found in 147ms (ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)


Started GET "/dashboard/dispatch" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-01 12:57:29 -0600

ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0):
  app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:6:in `dispatch'

Started POST "/__better_errors/46170ad487ddedf4/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-01 12:57:29 -0600
```

Using `devise gem` for authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need try a different method name other than `dispatch` .
As [dispatch](https://apidock.com/rails/Dispatcher/dispatch/class) is a rails method.

Comment: that was exactly the problem. Thanks! Ill go re-review the list of reserved words!